# How to start Solr Cloud collection without -e -cloud

Tags: solr

I use Solr Cloud for my project and I always start it with `bin/solr start -e -cloud` that always prompt all the questions for making a new collection or re-use one.

But is there a command that can directly start the collection I want, like `bin/solr start [collectionName] -cloud -p 8983`?

I didn't find anything in the Solr Manual.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All collections are available by default, so starting Solr in cloud mode should be enough.

```
bin/solr start -c
```

The default port is 8983, so there is no need to give the `-p` parameter unless you're changing it.

Comment: Hm.. if I start the cloud with this command, I don't see any collection in the API. It only appears when I start the example and select "re-use"

Comment: When you're using `-e`, you're in effect just using the example collections (at least that's my impression - I haven't used `-e` a lot). In that case you haven't really created your own collections for use - these can be created after starting the server in regular cloud mode - either through the Admin interface, through the API or using `solr create`.

Comment: I'm facing this exact issue (I want to start solr in cloud mode and connect to my existing collection). I can't find that command anywhere. Would love to know how to do `solr start -c  -? myCollection`

Comment: I'm not sure what "connect to my existing collection" mean; are you talking about adding nodes to a cluster? Or do you have a collection stored on disk on a node, but want to import it? Create a proper question with all relevant details instead of asking in the comments of another answer :-)